# How can i test with jest a react component who use context api?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

***My problem is:***

- I use the react's context api `<StateConsumer></StateConsumer>` to retrieve `value.connected` to know if my is connected.
  I want to use jest to simulate a connected user.

***My code is :***

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import SignPage from '../Connection/SignPage';
    import OgdpcQuery from '../Ogdpc/OgdpcQuery/OgdpcQuery';
    import {StateConsumer} from '../../api/context';

    export default class Landing extends Component {

    render() {

    return (
        <StateConsumer>
            {(value) => {
                if (value.connected === false){
                return (
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="row">
                            {/* State information on the profile */}
                            <SignPage/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                        {/* component who ll come to display login of each PS invitation */}
                            {/* <OgdpcRequest/> */}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
                else if(value.connected === true){
                    return (
                        <div className="container">
                            <h1>connected</h1>
                        </div>
                    )
                } 
            }}
        </StateConsumer>
       )
       }
       }
```

I want to make a test with jest :

The following statement (value.connected) as to be false if i want this one to be validate `expect(wrapper).to.contain(<SignPage/>)`

I tried this code to understand how jest work. I don't how to test the code above (my landing component):

```
import {expect} from 'chai';
import React from 'react';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import Landing from '../component/Landing/Landing';
import {StateConsumer} from '../api/context';

describe('<Landing />', () => {

let wrapper;
beforeEach(() => { wrapper = shallow(<Landing />, {context: true})})

const ContextConsumer = <ContextConsumer connected={true}/>

it('Test to look if something insine <Landing />', () => {
    console.log('wrapper ===> ', wrapper.debug({ ignoreProps: true }));
    expect(wrapper).to.contain(<SignPage/>); 
})

}
)
```

My app is full of stuffs like this, so i can't move forward.

I read a lot of docs but i did not understand really how it work! Jest look really hard to me at first, init mock and fake function look weird to me. I think after fews weeks on it this will be more obvious for me! So if you have some advises, docs very understable novice or help it will be awesome

Sorry if this post look pretty bad because of my english or formulation. thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution for my case :

```
describe('<Landing />', () => {
it('Test to look if something inside <Landing />', () => {
        const wrapper  = mount(
            <StateProvider>
                <Landing />
            </StateProvider>
        );
        wrapper.setState({connected : false});
        expect(wrapper).to.contain(<SignPage/>);
    }
)
```

with `wrapper.setState({connected : false});` I was able to set my local state to "false" and simulate a user not connected on the page and check if my SignPage component was there.

I don't know if it's the best way but for me it's work fine.